# How to make the title centered with respect to the header line?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, fancyhdr

I have the following code for some document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{..}
\rhead{..}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\Large{..}

\newline

\newline

\large{..}

\end{center}

\section{}
..

\end{document}
```

My question is: When I compile the code, it looks as if the text is centered with respect to the paper, but not to the header line, so it is does not look right. Is there a way to fix this? If so, what changes should I make to my code?

Also, apologies for the way I wrote the code above. If someome could edit it and also tell me how to write it properly (for this site) that would be great.

Comment: try the geometry package. perhaps your margins need setting.

Comment: With those settings the rule *will* be centered with respect to the page, unless you're using A4 paper for the printout. So centering with respect to the paper or the rule is just the same.

Comment: @egreg Does this mean I don't need to make any changes? It is just the case that it looks off centered wrt the header line?

Comment: Actually I am using A4 paper for the printout. What should I change?

Comment: @CAF `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}`